# How to create custom "Request Body is Missing" error in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, exception, error-handling

To create custom error, we need to know what kind of Exception error it is. The problem is I cannot determine what kind of error the "request body is missing one" is. At first I thought it was categorized as `MethodArgumentNotValidException` , but it doesn't catch the error.

I create the Controller Advice for the error

```java
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        MyObject<Object> error = MyObject.failure("Invalid Parameter");
        log.error("argument invalid", exception);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/tes")
public MyObject<MyRes> myTest(@Valid @RequestBody MyReq req, HttpServletRequest hsReq) throws Exception{
        return myService.updateTestData(req);
}
```

I used Postman to call the API.

*** First Trial with bracket**

[image: with bracket]

*** Second Trial - without bracket**

[image: without bracket]

No error occurred.

My question is, how to handle this error, When no request body attached at all in the request. I want to return the "invalid param" error in this case too.

Comment: Aren't you using the validation annotations? Those create the error responses for you (and can validate for required params). If you want to customize the error message beyond that, create a @Component that extends DefaultErrorAttributes and override getErrorAttributes.

Comment: @SledgeHammer yeah, I did. but it doesn't catch the exception if I didn't put the bracket. I didn't understand why it works only if I put the bracket, and didn't recognize the missing body if I remove the bracket. 

If I removed the custom error msg or remove the `@ControllerAdvise` , the default msg error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but you might want to try adding this on your ControllerAdvice class, that's how I caught the *Required request body is missing* error when trying to send an empty request.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingRequestBody(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Answer (score 0):

One way of do it is overriding the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` method in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

```
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    // 400 BAD REQUEST HANDLER
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        val errorMessage = "Request body is missing";
        log.error("400 BAD REQUEST: " + errorMessage);
        return this.handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorMessage, headers, status, request);
    }
}
```